# How to split a string by using [] in Python

Tags: python, string

So from this string:

"name[id]"

I need this:

"id"

I used str.split ('[]'), but it didn't work. Does it only take a single delimiter?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
import re 
s = "name[id]"
re.find(r"\[(.*?)\]", s).group(1) # = 'id'
```

`str.split()` takes a string on which to split input.  For instance:

```
"i,split,on commas".split(',') # = ['i', 'split', 'on commas']
```

The `re` module also allows you to split by regular expression, which can be *very* useful, and I think is what you meant to do.

```
import re
s = "name[id]"

# split by either a '[' or a ']'
re.split('\[|\]', s) # = ['name', 'id', '']
```

Comment: In all the time I've spent on SO, this is the first question where I thought "Use a regex!" instead of "Oh my good, don't use a regex for THIS!" :)

Comment: Still no need for a regex. All that punctuation offends my eyes!

Comment: Haha - I thought the same exact thing @Torsten

Comment: This shouldn't be using a lazy dot. Try r"\\[([^][]+)\\]" instead to reduce backtracking. (Yes, it looks weird, but it works.) It probably won't matter much on such short strings, but the lazy dot is a bad habit.

Answer (score 7):

Either

```
"name[id]".split('[')[1][:-1] == "id"
```

or

```
"name[id]".split('[')[1].split(']')[0] == "id"
```

or

```
re.search(r'\[(.*?)\]',"name[id]").group(1) == "id"
```

or

```
re.split(r'[\[\]]',"name[id]")[1] == "id"
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the delimiter is the whole string argument passed to split. So your example would only split a string like 'name[]id[]'.

Try eg. something like:

```
'name[id]'.split('[', 1)[-1].split(']', 1)[0]

'name[id]'.split('[', 1)[-1].rstrip(']')
```

Comment: Nice! Now write one for "matrix[0][1][2]"

Comment: heh! [subscript.rstrip(']') for subscript in 'matrix[0][1][2]'.split('[')[1:]]. Next! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a fan of regex, but in cases like it often provides the best solution.

Triptych already recommended this, but I'd like to point out that the ?P<> group assignment can be used to assign a match to a dictionary key:

```
>>> m = re.match(r'.*\[(?P<id>\w+)\]', 'name[id]')
>>> result_dict = m.groupdict()
>>> result_dict
{'id': 'id'}
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need regular expressions for this.  The .index() function and string slicing will work fine.

Say we have:

```
>>> s = 'name[id]'
```

Then:

```
>>> s[s.index('[')+1:s.index(']')]
'id'
```

To me, this is easy to read: "start one character after the [ and finish before the ]".

Answer (score 1):

```
def between_brackets(text):
    return text.partition('[')[2].partition(']')[0]
```

This will also work even if your string does not contain a `[…]` construct, and it assumes an implied `]` at the end in the case you have only a `[` somewhere in the string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to python and this is an old question, but maybe this?

`str.split('[')[1].strip(']')`

Comment: Prior art by bobince and please don't use the keyword "str" for variable names!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of the list use []. For example, create a list from URL like below with split.

```
>>> urls = 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/'
```

This generates a list like the one below.

```
>>> print( urls.split("/") )
['http:', '', 'quotes.toscrape.com', 'page', '11', '']
```

And what if you wanna get value only "http" from this list? You can use like this

```
>>> print(urls.split("/")[0])
http:
```

Or what if you wanna get value only "1" from this list? You can use like this

```
>>> print(urls.split("/")[-2])
1
```

Answer (score -1):

str.split uses the entire parameter to split a string. Try:

```
str.split("[")[1].split("]")[0]
```

Comment: Wrong - str.split takes a string of any length

Comment: I think Tyson was saying that str.split("[]") will split on the entire paramter i.e. "[]" and not "[" "]" individually. Nothing wrong with his answer.

Comment: "str" is a keyword in Python, so you should avoid using it as a variable name in examples!